# Solving the recurrence relationship $n a_{n+1} = (n + 1) a_n + a_0$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I was playing around with an interesting functional equation and came upon the recurrence relationship  $n a_{n+1} = (n + 1) a_n + a_0$. I tried to employ a generating function to solve it, but I could not think of the proper operator to express the equation. Taking

$$\phi(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$$

I rewrote the equation as

$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} na_{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 0} (n + 1) a_n + \sum_{n \geq 0} a_0 x^n
$$

Considering $x$ to be in the interval of convergence for all series we have $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_0 x^n = \frac{a_0}{1-x}$. I tried inserting the operator $x \frac{d}{dx}$ into various parts of the equation, but did not have much luck. Can this recurrence be solved by conventional methods?

**Edit:** The only other idea that I had would be to introduce a change of variables by considering $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$ and $b_0 = a_0$. Then, $n(a_{n+1} - a_n) = a_n + a_0$ would imply that $n b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k + a_0$

Comment: $n=0$ gives $a_0=0$ which is a little bit strange though

Comment: @Hypernova Probably the recurrence relation only holds for $n\geq 1$ (I guess).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recurrence relation $n a_{n+1} = (n + 1) a_n + a_0$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_n}n+\frac{a_0}{n(n+1)}=\frac{a_n}n+\frac{a_0}{n}-\frac{a_0}{n+1}.$$
Now, telescoping:
$$\frac{a_n}n-\frac{a_1}1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{a_k}k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{a_0}{k}-\frac{a_0}{k+1}\right)=a_0-\frac{a_0}n.$$
Hence $a_n=na_1+(n-1)a_0$.